# "Calls to the web service will fail..." Once Again

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

Last year someone reported encountering this problem ("The Silverlight project you are about to debug uses web services.  Calls to the web service will fail unless the silverlight project is hosted in and launched from the same web project that contains the web services.") and accepted the answer to "set the web project which hosts the Silverlight application to be your startup project."

I'm seeing the same message, but think the solution might have to be different.  I am building in VS 2010 a Silverlight application to access the Google Weather API, with VB as the code-behind.  The API will return a XML file with data for the specified city (ex., "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=london,england").  The Solution Explorer only shows my VB/Silverlight project ("GetWeather"), and the Project Properties dialog box shows the Startup Object as "GetWeather.App" -- the only choice.  I'm trying to use a WebClient object to make the call and an XDocument object to parse the return.  But I repeatedly get the above error message, with no other result.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a simple Web project and configure it to host the Silverlight app. You'll need to host the app somewhere anyways, so why not create a stub ASP.NET application in your solution? The easiest way is to create a new Silverlight app solution selecting an ASP.NET web project as the host, and then copying your existing code to that solution. Then you should set the web project as the startup one. This should make debugging **a lot** easier.

Besides, do remember to configure the client access policy to enable cross-domain calls. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#crossdomain_communication)